# MFC how to get resource ID in different file?

Tags: c++, mfc

I am new mfc and english is not good
but I have a question

How can I get Edit ID in different file?

My edit ID name is **IDC_MYEDIT_EDIT**(m_myEdit_Edit)
I tried to use in new cpp file for it

main cpp is MainMFCDlg.cpp

myNewCppFile is MyNew.cpp

in MyNew.cpp

```
CMainMFCDlg* MainMFCDlg = (CMainMFCDlg*)AfxGetMainWnd();
    CString myString;
    MainMFCDlg ->m_myEdit_Edit.GetDlgItemTextW(*IDC_MYEDIT_EDIT*, myString);
                                                   //here is erro, How can I get 'IDC_MYEDIT_EDIT' in MyNew.cpp? 
                                                   and also I tried ***MainDlg->IDC_MYEDIT_EDIT***  but failed.
```

Comment: `#include "resource.h"` in your include stack, if it a normal MFC application. Your project should have one that manages all of the user resource constants sprinkled throughout your resource file and application. At least I think that's the name (been like 20 years since I sullied myself with an MFC application).

Comment: That doesn't sound like a resource ID at all. Seems you are looking for a control ID instead. Those are very different things. If that is something that confuses you, spend some more time learning the fundamentals. In other words: Put MFC to the side until you are proficient in Windows API programming. [This book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X) is mandatory reading.

Comment: As mentioned, all your control ID values are maintained in the resource.h file. So # include it wherever required.

Comment: *"all your control ID values are maintained in the resource.h file"* - That's not correct. It is where the resource editor puts ID values, by default. There is neither a requirement to use the resource editor, nor even use symbolic constants for control IDs. If you decide to assign symbolic names to control IDs, there's no reason to put them into any particular file, certainly not a global file used by everyone.

Comment: I second IInspectable.
Besides, resource.h is the default filename for the resources. This name can be changed.
Right-clicking on the root of resource view brings up the dialog where resource.h can be changed to any name desired.

Comment: @IInspectable Well, yes, you are right. But if the average jo bloggs is just going to use the editor as sis, IMHO it has always been like that. And if you your gonna change it all and do it all your own way, you'll have a good knowledge of all this and wouldn't be asking the question. So given the context ... But yes, I do stand corrected.